# how to emulate a shake with the cordova android emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, createjs

How can I do a shake event in this emulator to test my shaking actions ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use ripple to emulate accelerometer
[You will find Ripple here](http://ripple.incubator.apache.org/)

[This page will get you started](http://codingsquare.blogspot.co.nz/2014/01/using-ripple-to-emulate-apache-cordova.html)

On said page

> Accelerometer
>
> The accelerometer allows us to emulate the device motion changes using accelerometer  framework. You might as well emulate shaking the device to test the device motion changes. You can use the device icon in this section to emulate the device motion actions.